# How to show data in second spinner based on data chosen in first spinner?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am putting my data in spinners.Data is coming from URL.How to make spinner so that when syllabus is ICSE is chosen it reflect only those grade, subject which has ICSE?

**My JSON**

```
  {  
     "results":[  
  {  
     "syllabus":"CBSE",
     "grade":"5",
     "subject":"Kannada",
     "topic":"Grammar Level 1",
     "id":28
  },

  {  
     "syllabus":"CBSE",
     "grade":"5",
     "subject":"Science",
     "topic":"The Natural  Calamities",
     "id":16
  },


  {  
     "syllabus":"CBSE",
     "grade":"6",
     "subject":"Science",
     "topic":"Movement in Animals",
     "id":116
  },

  {  
     "syllabus":"CBSE",
     "grade":"6",
     "subject":"Social Studies",
     "topic":"Contact With Distant Lands",
     "id":59
  },

  {  
     "syllabus":"CBSE",
     "grade":"6",
     "subject":"Social Studies",
     "topic":"Gupta Empire",
     "id":34
  },   


  "id":148
  },
  {  
     "syllabus":"ICSE",
     "grade":"6",
     "subject":"Computers",
     "topic":"Introduction to QBASIC Programming",
     "id":44
  },


  {  
     "syllabus":"ICSE",
     "grade":"6",
     "subject":"Social Studies - History",
     "topic":"The Vedic Age",
     "id":42
  },
  {  
     "syllabus":"Entrance Exam - Karnataka CET",
     "grade":"12",
     "subject":"Mathematics",
     "topic":"Previous Year Question Papers",
     "id":121
  },
  {  
     "syllabus":"Entrance Exam - Karnataka CET",
     "grade":"12",
     "subject":"Science - Biology",
     "topic":"Previous Year Question Papers",
     "id":117
  },
  {  
     "syllabus":"Entrance Exam - Karnataka CET",
     "grade":"12",
     "subject":"Science - Chemistry",
     "topic":"Previous Year Question Papers",
     "id":110
  },
  {  
     "syllabus":"Entrance Exam - Karnataka CET",
     "grade":"12",
     "subject":"Science - Physics",
     "topic":"Previous Year Question Papers",
     "id":104
  }

   }
```

**Any help will be great for me**

**MainActivity Class**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;

JSONArray jsonarray2;
JSONObject jsonobject2;

ArrayList<String> worldlist;
ArrayList<String> worldlist2;
ArrayList<String> worldlist3;
ArrayList<Results> world;
TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topic);
    // Download JSON file AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();

}

// Download JSON file AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        world = new ArrayList<Results>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner
        worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        worldlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        worldlist3 = new ArrayList<String>();

        // JSON file URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("https://www.wonderslate.com/funlearn/topicsMap");

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Results worldpop = new Results();

                worldpop.setSyllabus(jsonobject.optString("syllabus"));






                worldpop.setGrade(jsonobject.optString("grade"));
                worldpop.setSubject(jsonobject.optString("subject"));
                worldpop.setId(jsonobject.optString("id"));
                world.add(worldpop);


                worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("syllabus"));
                worldlist2.add(jsonobject.optString("grade"));
                worldlist3.add(jsonobject.optString("subject"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml

        final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.syllabus);
        final Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.grade);
        Spinner mySpinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subject);

        // Spinner adapter


        final LinkedHashSet<String>[] listToSet = new LinkedHashSet[]{new LinkedHashSet<String>(worldlist)};

        //Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
        final List<String> worldlistnew = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet[0]);


        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlistnew));


        //Creating ArrayList without duplicate values

        listToSet[0] = new LinkedHashSet<String>(worldlist3);
        //Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
        final List<String> worldlistnew3 = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet[0]);
        mySpinner3
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlistnew3));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                       if (mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CBSE")) {

                           // if (mySpinner.getId() == R.id.syllabus)




                            listToSet[0] = new LinkedHashSet<String>(worldlist2);

                            final List<String> worldlistnew2 = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet[0]);


                            mySpinner2
                                    .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                                            worldlistnew2));


                            textView.setText("21");


                        } else if (mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("ICSE")) {
                            textView.setText("31");
                        } else if (mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Entrance Exam - Karnataka CET"))

                        {
                            textView.setText("41");

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

    }
}

private void resetGrade(String grade) {
}
```

}

Comment: you can sub List a data of your main list according to the selection of value from spinner and then display the data in sub spinner. 
Like If you have selected the value from Spinner is x then get x position's value and iterate it and match it in entire list if you you found then make a sub list and add matched item  to it  and then display it in secondary spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines first from doInBackground method. No need to create separate arraylist here..

```
worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("syllabus"));
            worldlist2.add(jsonobject.optString("grade"));
            worldlist3.add(jsonobject.optString("subject"));
```

Declare these arraylist globally...

```
ArrayList<String> syllabuslist;
    ArrayList<String> gradlist;
    ArrayList<String> subjectlist;
```

and initialize these spinner in OnCreate method before calling Async task(DownloadJSON())

```
 Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.syllabus);
 Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.grade);
 Spinner mySpinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subject);
```

Now set spinner in onPostExecute() method....remove extra code you have written in onPostExcute...just copy my code

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        // Spinner adapter
        syllabuslist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Results bean : world) {
            syllabuslist.add(bean.getSyllabus());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, syllabuslist);

        adapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {

                String syllabus_name = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();


                gradlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < world.size(); i++) {

                    if (world.get(i).getSyllabus().equals(syllabus_name)) {
                        gradlist.add(world.get(i).getGrade());
                    }

                }

                setGradeSpinner();//its a method to create grade spinner
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
    }


        public void setGradeSpinner(){

            if(gradlist!=null && gradlist.size()>0)
            {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, gradlist);

                adapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                mySpinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

                mySpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                               int arg2, long arg3) {

                        String grade_name = mySpinner2.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();


                        subjectlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < world.size(); i++) {

                            if (world.get(i).getGrade().equals(grade_name)) {
                                subjectlist.add(world.get(i).getSubject());
                            }

                        }

                       // setSubjectSpinner();//its a method to create subject spinner like as I do for garde spinner
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                    }
                });

            }

    }
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: thanks ...just tried your code and one compilation error is there.Compiler is telling to initialise gradelist.

Comment: gradlist= new ArrayList<String>();          add just before for loop

Comment: I am getting the same thing what I was getting previously.It shows all the data in the second spinner regardless of what I chose in the first spinner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104997/discussion-between-vishal-chauhan-and-shwetabh-singh).

Comment: how to remove the duplicates from arraylist? I tried like this   protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.syllabus);
            // Spinner adapter
            syllabuslist = new ArrayList<String>();

            HashSet<String> listToSet = new HashSet<String>(syllabuslist);

//Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
            ArrayList<String> syllabuslistWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);   not  happening.

Comment: Are you sure that your are using syllabuslistWithoutDuplicates in adapter. In this line **ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, syllabuslistWithoutDuplicates );**      because your way for removing duplicates is right.

Comment: Hey, I fetch all the data but unable to get the id. I am converting id to string and then trying to get it as you mention. But  the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

In your onitemclick listener of your first spinner, depending on the item selected change the list data of your second spinner and call.

```
         spinner2Adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

You dont have to create a new adapter and list every time you change selection in spinner1.

Comment: Make sure that the list you are sending to second spinner and the second spinner adapter is initialized only once.

Answer (score 0):

@Shwetabh Singh I cannt understand your question.But i have done one city select example. You can refere it. Here In first Spinner i list city name. and based on the city select second spinner area is refcted

```
{
  "City": [
    {
      "name": "Ahmedabad",
      "City_area1" : "Ghatlodia",
      "City_area2" : "Chandlodia",
      "City_area3" : "Other"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hydarabad",
      "City_area1" : "IIT",
      "City_area2" : "Faridabad",
      "City_area3" : "Other"
    },
    {
      "name": "Noida",
      "City_area1" : "Sector-50",
      "City_area2" : "Sector-41",
      "City_area3" : "Other"
    }
  ]
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner selectcityspinner;
ArrayList<String> citylist;
ArrayList<city> cityandarealist;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    selectcityspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selectcityspin);
    citylist = new ArrayList<>();
    new cityAsynTask().execute("Jason data url");//put your url over here
}
public class cityAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        cityandarealist = new ArrayList<city>();

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jobjcity = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jobjcity.getJSONArray("City");
                for (int i = 0;i < jarray.length();i++){
                    city city = new city();
                    JSONObject jrealobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    city.setCity(jrealobject.getString("name"));
                    city.setArea1(jrealobject.getString("City_area1"));
                    city.setArea2(jrealobject.getString("City_area2"));
                    city.setArea3(jrealobject.getString("City_area3"));
                    cityandarealist.add(city);
                    citylist.add(jrealobject.getString("name"));

                }
                return true;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if(aBoolean == false){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"data isnot recieved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else  {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,citylist);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            selectcityspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            selectcityspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String Country = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Spinner selectareaspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectareaspin);
                    List<String> AreaList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    AreaList.add(cityandarealist.get(position).getArea1());
                    AreaList.add(cityandarealist.get(position).getArea2());
                    AreaList.add(cityandarealist.get(position).getArea3());
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AreaList);
                    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    selectareaspinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Explain Your requirement.

Comment: See in my json board is repeated cbse,icse etc.so in the first spinner if board is chosen icse then I want to show only those grades/class which has icse {  
     "syllabus":"CBSE",
     "grade":"5",
     "subject":"Kannada",
     "topic":"Grammar Level 1",
     "id":28
  },